# Nouveau unknown chipset at install

Tags: boot, system-installation, nouveau

I'm trying to install Ubuntu version 14.10 on my new computer. It's a fresh build with nothing installed yet. You can see a list of the hardware [here](http://pcpartpicker.com/p/3X6y99). At first I had difficulty with the UEFI boot, but I went into the BIOS and set everything that I could to "legacy". Now, when I try to boot, I get the following error:

> [ 2.817690 nouveau E[ DEVICE][0000:01:00.0] unknown chipset, 0x124020a1
>
> [ 2.817724 nouveau E[ DRM] failed to create 0x80000080, -22

I tried booting in nomodeset, which I thought did something to fix that, but it didn't work. I suspect it has something to do with not having any drivers yet, but I didn't get an optical drive. I was planning on just downloading them. What can I do?

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you managed to finally install Ubuntu and drivers?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/598417/nouveau-unknown-chipset-on-installer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

login and do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

see what is recommended

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-xxx` (xxx is your recommended driver)

reboot.