# nouveau "unknown chipset" On Installer

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 14.10

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.10, however when I boot, a nouveau "unknown chipset", "failed to create" error is all that is on the screen (just black with white text). The computer then freezes completely and I am unable to install Ubuntu. The graphics card I am using is an **Nvidia ASUS GTX 960 Strix**.

Is it possible to install Ubuntu with alternative drivers? Is there a way to install with a text only mode?  The CPU is an AMD chip so there I cannot use an Intel graphics driver.

If I can install it and get to a TTY then I can install the proprietary Nvidia driver myself but I cannot even boot the installer at this point.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/567965/nouveau-error-unknown-chipset-during-startup-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Press <kbd>e</kbd> at the bootloader to enter the bootloader and press <kbd>e</kbd> again to enter the kernel options. Then add `nomodeset rdblacklist=nouveau` to the end of the line that begins with `linux` and boot the system.

After you install the system, download the proper driver for your card, run:

```
chmod +x _name_of_your_driver.run
```

and type `init 3` in terminal to enter runlevel 3. Login as root, and run the installer. If you have any issues you want to update the kernel, read this: http://www.wikihow.com/Update-Ubuntu-Kernel

Answer (score 4):

Adding [How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu) as a reference for more details. Basically, hit `e` at the grub boot selection to modify how that entry boots and add `nomodeset rdblacklist=nouveau` to the line that starts with `linux` and probably includes the word `splash`. Make sure you add it before the `---`.