# Unknown Chipset Nouveau

Tags: nouveau

I' m trying to install Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS on my desktop pc. After booting ubuntu from USB-Drive it was saying "Unknown chipset nouveau". By following this guide [Guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598417/nouveau-unknown-chipset-on-installer) I was able to install the OS. But when I try to boot Ubuntu I get nothing on my screen. The only thing I see is a black screen with a blinking underscore.

What might be the problem?

Comment: There us no "Ubuntu 18" desktop version. Probably you need Nvidia drivers, but you gave no information at all.

Comment: Sorry for giving less information. I m talking about Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver). I currently have Nvidia RTX 3080 TI.

Comment: It’s not the answer to your problem, but is there any reason you’re using a version of Ubuntu that is almost out of support? 22.04 is available, 20.04 has been well tested for the past 2 years if you want an os that’s been around for a while.

Comment: A workaround for me was to plug the display into the motherboard instead of the graphics card. This fixed the problem of not having a visual output after booting for the first time for me.

Answer (score 2):

You need nvidia drivers. While booting, boot into recovery mode. then from the menu enable networking and choose dpkg (in that order) and finally choose the root (drop to terminal) option.

Once you have done that, you will need to conect to wifi (if its a laptop) or just plugin an ethernet cable to connect to internel. Once you have internet working (test by doing `ping 8.8.8.8` ), install the correct nvidia drivers.

Generally:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-470
```

--OR--

```
sudo apt install nvidia-510
```

For really old cards:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-340
```

Then exit and resume.

Comment: Hey, thx for your reply. The Problem is I m not able to boot the System so GRUB is not booting. When I start my pc I only see the information about my Motherboard and then a black screen.

Comment: Well, in that case it seems that your system has a non working OS install. If you have never used the system, I recommend installing Kubuntu 22.04 (it has some of the best hardware support among the *ubuntu versions) again. It seems your current setup is too new for 18.04 hardware support.

Comment: The syntax seems to have changed and it did not work for me. `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-510` worked

Answer (score 0):

"You need nvidia drivers. While booting, boot into recovery mode. then from the menu enable networking and choose dpkg (in that order) and finally choose the root (drop to terminal) option.

Once you have done that, you will need to conect to wifi (if its a laptop) or just plugin an ethernet cable to connect to internel. Once you have internet working (test by doing ping 8.8.8.8 ), install the correct nvidia drivers." This was an incredible answer. I have a brand new 4090 and found myself in the same situation. If you get stuck, follow the steps above but download the relevant drivers for yourself by using this link: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux i selected to do it over the network and it worked very well.